# RBF kernel for classification using KNN

Tags: python, python-2.7, classification, similarity, knn

Here is `X` is the training matrix and `test_feature` is a test array.

```
squared_euclidian = np.sum(np.square(X - test_feature), axis=1)
```

`squared_euclidian` is the [Squared Euclidian distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#Squared_Euclidean_distance)

For the euclidian distance of in input array with a complete numpy matrix

```
dist = np.sqrt(squared_euclidian)
```

and for RBF (gaussian) kernel as per [this](http://research.cs.tamu.edu/prism/lectures/pr/pr_l19.pdf) Slide 5

```
test_sigma = np.square(np.std(test_feature))
dist = np.exp(-1 * (squared_euclidian / test_sigma))
```

I tested these functions on a dataset of 2000 instances where I got 91% accuracy for euclidian but 54% for the other.

Is the formula for RBF kernel wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this the right formula as I see it on slide 5?

```
dist = np.exp(-.5 * squared_euclidian / np.square(test_feature.std()))
```

Have a look at the notes [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html) about the bias an estimator for `np.std(ddof=...)`